# Warning punteros c

Tags: c++, c, punteros

Tengo un problema en el siguiente codigo y necesito ayuda para solucionarlo. Gracias de antemano

```
float *calculaFn(int n ,Algoritmo a, Caso c){   

  float fn[2];  
  if(a==INSERCION){    
    if(c==ORDEN_ASC){  // f(n)'s algoritmo insercion orden ascendente  
        fn[0] = log(n);        
        fn[1] = n;           
        fn[2] = (n*log(n));   
    }else if(c==ORDEN_RAND){  // f(n)'s algoritmo insercion orden 
  aleatorio  
        fn[0] = (n*log(n));   
        fn[1] = (pow(n,2));   
        fn[2] = (pow(n,2.1));  
    }else{ // f(n)'s algoritmo insercion orden descendente  
        fn[0] = pow(n,1.8);  
        fn[1] = pow(n,2);     
        fn[2] = pow(n,2.2);   
    }  
  }else{  
    if(c==ORDEN_ASC){  //algoritmo rapido orden ascendente  
      fn[0] = pow(n,.8);   
      fn[1] = pow(n,.92)*log(n);  
      fn[2] = pow(n,1.2);     
    }else if(c==ORDEN_RAND){ // f(n)'s algoritmo rapido orden aleatorio  
      fn[0] = pow(n,.8);  
      fn[1] = pow(n,.92)*log(n);  
      fn[2] = pow(n,1.2);    
    }else{ // f(n)'s algoritmo rapido orden descendente  
      fn[0] = pow(n,.8);   
      fn[1] = pow(n,.92)*log(n);  
      fn[2] = pow(n,1.2);      
    }  
  }  
  return &fn;     <------Me salta el siguiente warning aqui  
}
```

> p2.c: In function ‘calculaFn’:
>   p2.c:227:10: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>   return &fn;
>   ---------^
>   p2.c:227:10: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]

Answer (score 2):

```
float *calculaFn(int n ,Algoritmo a, Caso c){   
  float fn[2];
  ...
  return &fn;
}
```

Dos problemas:

- En C/C++, un array es efectivamente un puntero. Es decir, `return fn;` es (por lo que hace referencia a tipos), correcto. Al añadir una indirección, lo que devuelves es `float **`.
- `fn` está definido como una variable local. En el *stack*. Eso significa que, una vez salgas del método, esas posiciones del stack estarán disponibles para ser usadas por otros métodos. Que podrán sobreescribirlas.

  P.ej, prueba a añadir un método

  ```
  float *machacaFn(int n, Algoritmo a, Caso c) {
    float otroNombre[2];
    otroNombre[0] = 42.0;
    otroNombre[1] = 69.0;
    return NULL;
  }
  ```

  y

  ```
  float miFloat1, miFloat2, *fn2;
  fn2 = calculaFn(1, a, c);
  machacaFn(1, a, c);
  miFloat1 = *fn2;
  fn2++;
  miFloat2 = *fn2;
  cin << miFloat1 << " - " << miFloat2 << endl;
  ```

  En la llamada a `machacaFn`, la variable `otroNombre` ocupará la misma posición de memeoria que ocupaba `fn` y al escribir en ella sobreescribirás los valores que te devolvía la función `calculaFn`.

  Si quieres definir una variable que persista después de la llamada a método, tienes que obtenerla del *heap*, ya sea con `malloc` o `new`.

Answer (score 2):

El primer problema de `calcularFn` es que el array está mal dimensionado:

```
float *calculaFn(int n ,Algoritmo a, Caso c){   

  float fn[2];  // <<--- 1
  if(a==INSERCION){    
    if(c==ORDEN_ASC){  // f(n)'s algoritmo insercion orden ascendente  
        fn[0] = log(n);        
        fn[1] = n;           
        fn[2] = (n*log(n)); // <<--- 2
```

Si bien en `1` se ve que `fn` es un array para dos elementos de tipo `float`, en `2` vemos cómo se le da valor a un tercer elemento. Este tercer elemento **no pertenece** al array, por lo que su valor puede sobreescribir otras variables y viceversa.

`fn` debería tener capacidad para 3 elementos en vez de únicamente 2.

Como te han comentado, los arrays de tamaño fijo como `fn` son tratados como si fuesen punteros. De hecho, puedes comprobar fácilmente que puedes usar punteros para *apuntar* al contenido de `fn`:

```
float fn[2];
float* ptr = fn; // OK, el compilador no se queja
```

Pues bien, retornar `&n` implica devolver un puntero doble `float **` y para el compilador, un puntero doble como `float**` no es convertible a un puntero simple `float*

```
float *calculaFn(int n ,Algoritmo a, Caso c){   
  float fn[3];
  ...
  return &fn; // &(float[]) == &(float*) == float**
}
```

Entonces claro, la que aparentemente se presenta como la solución rápida pasa por eliminar la indirección:

```
float *calculaFn(int n ,Algoritmo a, Caso c){   
  float fn[3];
  ...
  return fn;
}
```

Pero entonces nos encontramos con otro problema, y es que `fn` es una variable local cuya vida está restringida a la llamada `calculaFn`. Es decir, cuando el programa abandona esta función, la variable `fn` deja de existir y la memoria que ocupaba puede ser utilizada sin restricciones por otras variables.

Para conseguir tus propósitos, de forma *legal*, es decir, sin hacer artificios raros, tienes varias opciones:

**1. Usar memoria dinámica**

Si conviertes el array de tamaño fijo en un puntero *de verdad* y lo redireccionas al *heap* (memoria dinámica), ya no tendrás problemas pues tu eres el responsable de gestionar la vida de la memoria alojada en el *heap*:

```
float *calculaFn(int n ,Algoritmo a, Caso c){   
  float* fn = new float[3];
  ...
  return fn;
}
```

Eso sí, no olvides liberar la memoria cuando ya no sea necesaria:

```
float* ptr = calculaFn(/* ... */);
// ...
delete[] ptr;
```

**2. Usa `static`**

La otra posibilidad es que la variable sea estática. Al ser estática ya no se aloja en la pila del programa sino en una región de memoria diferente, de tal forma que no su memoria no se liberará hasta que no finalice el programa... eso sí, la variable únicamente será accesible desde `calculaFn`.

El truco está en que `calculaFn` devuelve un puntero a la región de memoria donde se aloja la variable, por lo que sus valores podrán ser recuperados y/o modificados desde fuera de la función:

```
float *calculaFn(int n ,Algoritmo a, Caso c){   
  static float fn[3];
  ...
  return fn;
}
```

Como no hemos usado `new[]` no es necesario usar `delete`. Esta solución es, probablemente, la que mejor se adapta a tu código. Eso sí, dado que la variable es estática solo va a existir una instancia de la misma, por lo que hay que tener cuidado de no *pisar* su contenido sin querer:

```
float* ptr1 = calculaFn(/* parametros */);
std::cout << ptr1[0] << ' ' << ptr1[1] << ptr1[2] << '\n';

// Esta llamada modifica los valores de ptr1
float* ptr2 = calculaFn(/* otros parametros */);
std::cout << ptr1[0] << ' ' << ptr1[2] << ptr1[2] << '\n';
```

**3. Usa estructura de datos**

Las estructuras de datos existen para algo, y este sería un claro caso de uso. A diferencia de los arrays de tamaño fijo, las estructuras de datos pueden copiarse sin problemas. Fíjate que ya no sería necesario usar punteros:

```
struct DatosFn
{
  float dato1;
  float dato2;
  float dato3;
};

DatosFn calculaFn(int n, Algoritmo a, Caso c)
{
  // ...
}
```

**4. Usar std::Array**

He querido dejar para el final la que, desde mi punto de vista, es la mejor solución. Desde C++11 está disponible `std::array`. Este contenedor junta lo mejor de los arrays de tamaño fijo con lo mejor de la programación orientada a objetos. El resultado es un array de tamaño fijo con todo un juego de utilidades que simplifican su uso.

Resumiendo, los objetos de tipo `std::array`:

- Se pueden copiar
- Su acceso es equivalente al de los arrays de tamaño fijo
- Disponen de iteradores

Un posible ejemplo de implementación:

```
std::array<float,3> calculaFn(int n, Algoritmo a, Caso c)
{
  std::array<float,3> fn;

   if(a==INSERCION){    
     if(c==ORDEN_ASC){  // f(n)'s algoritmo insercion orden ascendente  
        fn[0] = log(n);        
        fn[1] = n;           
        fn[2] = (n*log(n));   
        // ...
   }

  return fn; 
}
```